# Why is $P[W \geq x]$, $W$ ~ $X^2(1)$ equal to $P(|Z| \geq \sqrt{x}), Z$ ~ $G(0,1)$

Tags: probability, statistics, normal-distribution, chi-squared

My textbook (statistics) says this as part of a larger example:

> = $P(W \geq x)$, $W$ ~ $X^2(1)$
>
> = $P(|Z| \geq \sqrt{x}), Z$ ~ $G(0,1)$

I understand that $X^2(1)$ ~ $G(0,1)^2$ for large enough values of $n$, so we square root both sides to get $Z$ and $\sqrt{x}$, but where do the absolute signs come from in the 2nd equation?

Comment: Hint: For reals $a$ and $b$, with $b \ge 0$ $$a^2 \ge b \iff |a|\ge \sqrt{b}$$

Comment: Define $X(1)$ and $G(0,1)$. What does $\sim$ mean here?